# varchar(8000) parameter does not truncate longer data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, types

I have two databases on two different machines. Both databases are connected with Link server. I am calling a stored procedure from one database defined in another database.

**In database A :-**

I have a stored procedure named as SP_1,

```
create proc SP_1 ( @aaa varchar(8000) )
begin    
 --Logic
end
```

**In database B :-**

I call *SP_1* of database A from database B.

If I pass more than 8000 characters to *SP_1* it accepts the argument.

If I would pass a 15000 character string to *SP_1* then ideally only 8000 character should be able to pass to *SP_1*, but it is taking all 15000 characters.

I am confused. **Why is the argument's value not truncated to 8000 characters?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this test script on two test databases `TEST_TT_1` and `TEST_TT_2`. It prints out:

> 15000

And

> 8000

So it definitely truncates the variable passed to the stored procedure.

```
USE TEST_TT_1;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test_proc
    @tp VARCHAR(8000)
AS
    SELECT LEN(@tp);
GO

USE TEST_TT_2;
DECLARE @tv VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @tv=REPLICATE(CAST('a' AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 15000);
SELECT LEN(@tv);
EXEC TEST_TT_1.dbo.test_proc @tv;
GO

USE TEST_TT_1;
GO
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.test_proc;
GO
```